# Alternative to absolute positioning of shapes' points

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if there was a way in WPF to create a shape (ex.: polygon, line, ...) but instead of using absolute positioning for the points of the shape, we could use something like percentage.

For example, instead of having a line with  absolute positioning like this: (X1=0,Y1=50,X2=100,Y2=50), we could have a line with percentage values (0 to 1) like this (X1=0,Y1=0.5, X2=1, Y2=0.5 where 1 is equivalent to the size of the parent). So no matter what is the size of the parent of the shape, the shape would always be proportional to its parent.

That could be done with dependency properties, but I would find it much cleaner if there was a way to do it with something like I described. I hope I didn't miss something really obvious that does exactly that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve a similar effect if you scale it by applying a scale transform on your geometry the size of the control.

```xaml
<Path Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Red">
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry  StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 1">
            <LineGeometry.Transform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Path}}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Path}}" />
            </LineGeometry.Transform>
        </LineGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

This should draw a red line with absolute points `(0, 0)` to `(100, 100)`.

Comment: That's a way to do it, but I was looking something more clean and less verbose. Something like `<Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0.5" Y2="0.5" Coordinates="Ratio" />`. The best way I found is to use a converter like this: `<Line X1="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Path}}" Converter="{StaticResource ratioConverter}" ConverterParameter="0.5"/>` but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: The best thing to do then would be to define your own path class applies the transform to the geometries given.  AFAIK, most if not all controls that uses this pattern doesn't have an option to change modes.  You should make your own if you desire this functionality.